# CQL User Defined Type data import Syntax Errors

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, user-defined-types

I have created  a UDT made up of fields from  three or four columns of data. One of the field contains a letter inside parens, for  example `(c)` or `(d)`. When importing the csv file using cqlsh's `COPY FROM`, I get an error message:

```
Syntax error in CQL query …..mismatched import  ‘(‘  expecting  ‘)’  (….column 3, column 4) VALUES (10.2[(]c…).
```

I have tried importing csv file with fields where the letter does not have brackets and get:

```
Syntax error in CQL query …..mismatched import  ‘c‘  expecting  ‘)’  (….column 3, column 4) VALUES (10.2[c]…)
```

I have tried importing csv file without a letter in the field and get:

```
Syntax error in CQL query …..mismatched import  ‘,‘  expecting  ‘)’  (….column 4) VALUES (10.2,…)
```

The UDT is made up of integers and text.  It appears that importing the csv file containing the UDT which includes a letter inside a bracket (e.g. `(c)`) generates a data violation as does a letter with no bracket as does  and as does field with no value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried character escaping using double dollar ($$) or double quotes ('') ? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html

Comment: I have imported data using  INSERT INTO  successfully and exported the data using    COPY TO  . I can see the csv file data format and am trying to replicate it with the format it uses e.g. '(c)'. Will provide comment if successful.